Should we use [identify-this-actor] for character identification, as its tag wiki suggests?
I've recently been adding the identify-this-actor tag to actor ID questions now that ID questions and ID tags are back.
According to the identify-this-actor tag wiki, the tag is meant for:

Identifying an actor or a character based on an image or a description.

This definition has been in the tag wiki since its introduction in 2013, more than a decade ago. It suggests that the tag isn't just for actor ID but also for character ID – even in cases where identifying the actor isn't necessary. I'm wondering if this dual-purpose use is something we want to continue, or if it might be better to create a separate tag specifically for character ID.
I'm bringing this up to ensure we're using our tags consistently. If we decide to stick with the current definition, then both actor and character ID questions should be tagged with identify-this-actor. (From what I've seen, many character ID questions aren't using this tag, so we'd need to do some retagging.)
However, if we prefer to separate these types of queries, we should retag the character-specific questions accordingly.
Watched/Ignored Tags list
Ideally, our solution should make it easy for users to manage their preferences. Those interested in character ID should be able to add a relevant tag to their "Watched Tags" list, while those who don't want to see ID questions should be able to filter them out via the "Ignored Tags" list. Using only one tag for everything character-related is inconvenient for users who'd have to either watch or ignore all character-related questions.
What are your thoughts on this? Should we continue using identify-this-actor for both purposes, or create a new tag for character ID?

Personally I believe we should restrict identify-this-actor to its limited descriptive purpose, identifying actual actors rather than confusing the issue.
Although I believe identification based solely on an image is a poor quality question (for indexing purposes and the fact that there are other actual image search options) we have decided to retain it.
However, character identification is, frankly, a niche question which could generally easily be answered by simple reference to other resources (IMDB / Credits etc.) since the OP will have access to the details of the movie which provided the image.
Granted there may be instances where the information is not readily available but I do not believe a tag other the already existing character than the movie name would be required.

"I do not believe a tag other the already existing [character] than the movie name would be required." Related: How should we tag music identification questions, considering that [soundtrack] exists?

A disadvantage of using [character] for all questions character-related, including ID, is that it removes the option for users to specifically watch or ignore character ID questions as per their tag watch/ignore preferences. They'd have to watch or ignore all character-related questions, which is inconvenient.

@galacticninja And yet Paulie_D's argumentation that character identification is something that rarely happens (and if it does, it almost always comes with further questions about the character anyway) pretty much alleviates this concern for making everyone and their grandma able to follow exactly that question categeory specifically.

@NapoleonWilson Sure, that's why I accepted the answer. Just stating a possible drawback. By the way, do you agree with AJ's similar argument on the [identify-this-song] tag? https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5091/1006 That " everyone and their grandma" won't want to watch or ignore music ID questions?

@galacticninja I don't see that being AJ's argument at all to begin with. o_O

@NapoleonWilson Yes, just like what you said about "everyone and their grandma" was also not my argument. Anyway, do you agree that music ID should have no ID tag, like character ID, and be lumped with [soundtrack], as AJ suggests, not allowing anyone to specifically watch or ignore music ID questions as per their Watched/Ignored tags list?

Watching/ignoring was precisely your argument, @galacticninja, if you like grandmas or not. ;-) But I'd say we'll reserve discussing that issue to its corresponding meta post, not that it ought to matter all too much to you or anyone else what I specifically think about that. In general, though, I don't tend to give too much weight to the supposed purpose of tags for serving as watch/ignore feeds, or we could do away with myriads of IMHO very useful tags that are really awful for watching/ignoring. Noone's gonna be interested in every damn plot-explanation question either.
